# Add a new column for Rank within each group in Data table

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to data.table in R and stuck in the following problem:

I have a data table X:

```
        date   hour      itemName            numberOfItem
 1: 2014-05-04   00       item-1                   54               
 2: 2014-05-04   00       item-2                   42               
 3: 2014-05-04   00       item-3                   33             
 4: 2014-05-04   00       item-4                   31              
 5: 2014-05-04   00       item-5                   30                
 6: 2014-05-04   00       item-6                   28                
 7: 2014-05-04   00       item-7                   27               
 8: 2014-05-04   00       item-7                   26     



----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

100000: 2014-08-08   23   item-n                   24
```

I have to add a new column Rank according to quantile for each of the group (date,hour) on the basis of column "numberOfItem". I was using this code to achieve this:

```
quantfun <- function(x) as.integer(cut(x, quantile(x, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE))
X[, Rank:= quantfun(numberOfItem),by="date,hour"]
```

But I was getting following error:

```
"Error in cut.default(x, quantile(x, probs = 0:4/4), include.lowest = TRUE) : 
  'breaks' are not unique"
```

Then I have done some de-bugging and found that some of the quantiles are same. So I am using following code:

```
       quantfun <- function(x) as.integer(cut(x, unique(quantile(x, probs=0:4/4)), include.lowest=TRUE)) 
       X[, Rank:= quantfun(numberOfItem),by="date,hour"]
```

But now I am getting following error:

```
"Error in cut.default(x, unique(quantile(x, probs = 0:4/4)), include.lowest = TRUE) : 
  invalid number of intervals"
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: I think the problem may be in `by="date,hour"`. Try `by = list(date,hour)` and let me know if that works. Also, please provide your data as the output from `dput` so we can reproduce your problem more easily

Comment: You should check `X[, length=.N, by=list(date, hour)][, min(length)]`.

Comment: Thanks Bernardo. I have tried your idea, but still getting same error.

Comment: The problem is most certainly with `cut` and has nothing to do with `data.table`. The error tells you this. You need to make your breaks unique

Comment: Roland: Minimum group length is 16.

Comment: Then check this: `X[, length=length(unique(numberOfItem)), by=list(date, hour)][, min(length)]`

Comment: The minimum value of numberOfItem in all groups is 1.

Comment: Well, there you have your problem. Look at the output of `quantile(rep(1, 5), probs=0:4/4)`. What is `cut` supposed to do with that.